# Reloading an operator for matrixes but it doesn't change the former matrix

Tags: c++

I have overloaded operators * and  *= with the same solution, though using operator *= doesn't seem to change the contents of the Matrix, maybe I am declaring the operator overload method incorrectly.

At the same time, operator * works properly and actually multiplies Matrix, I have checked it beforehand.

Output:

```
3 4 -5 
8 0 7 
8 9 -4 

8 7 7 
-6 0 6 
2 2 9 

3 4 -5 
8 0 7 
8 9 -4
```

Here is the code itself:

```
struct WrappedMatrix{
        int n;
        int ** Matrix;
    };

    struct WrappedVector{
        int n;
        int * Vector;
    };

    WrappedVector linearizedMatrix(WrappedMatrix matrix){
        WrappedVector vector;
        vector.n = matrix.n * matrix.n;
        vector.Vector = new int[vector.n];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.n; j++){
                 int k = j + (int) (i*sqrt(vector.n));
                 vector.Vector[k] = matrix.Matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        return vector;
    }

    WrappedMatrix normalMatrix(WrappedVector vector){
        WrappedMatrix matrix;
        matrix.n = sqrt(vector.n);
        matrix.Matrix = new int * [matrix.n];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.n; i++){
            matrix.Matrix[i] = new int[matrix.n];
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.n; j++){
                int k = j + (int) (i*sqrt(vector.n));
                matrix.Matrix[i][j] = vector.Vector[k];
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    WrappedVector operator*(const WrappedVector& vector1, const WrappedVector& vector2) {
        if(vector1.n != vector2.n) {
            cout << "Матриці різних розмірів!" << endl;
            return vector1;
        }
        WrappedMatrix matrix1 = normalMatrix(vector1);
        WrappedMatrix matrix2 = normalMatrix(vector2);
        WrappedMatrix result;
        result.n = matrix1.n;
        result.Matrix = new int * [result.n];
        for(int i = 0; i < result.n; i++){
            result.Matrix[i] = new int[result.n];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < result.n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < result.n; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < result.n; k++){
                    int p1 = matrix1.Matrix[i][k];
                    int p2 = matrix2.Matrix[k][j];
                    result.Matrix[i][j] += p1 * p2;
                }
            }
        }
        WrappedVector resultV = linearizedMatrix(result);
        return resultV;
    }

    //?
    WrappedVector operator*=(const WrappedVector& vector1, const WrappedVector& vector2) {
        if(vector1.n != vector2.n) {
            cout << "Матриці різних розмірів!" << endl;
            return vector1;
        }
        WrappedMatrix matrix1 = normalMatrix(vector1);
        WrappedMatrix matrix2 = normalMatrix(vector2);
        WrappedMatrix result;
        result.n = matrix1.n;
        result.Matrix = new int * [result.n];
        for(int i = 0; i < result.n; i++){
            result.Matrix[i] = new int[result.n];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < result.n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < result.n; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < result.n; k++){
                    int p1 = matrix1.Matrix[i][k];
                    int p2 = matrix2.Matrix[k][j];
                    result.Matrix[i][j] += p1 * p2;
                }
            }
        }
        WrappedVector resultV = linearizedMatrix(result);
        return resultV;
    }


    int main() {

        WrappedMatrix matrix;
        matrix.n = 3;


        matrix.Matrix = new int * [matrix.n];
            matrix.Matrix[0] = new int[matrix.n];
            matrix.Matrix[1] = new int[matrix.n];
matrix.Matrix[2] = new int[matrix.n];
            matrix.Matrix[0][0] = 3;
             matrix.Matrix[0][1] = 4;
             matrix.Matrix[0][2] = -5;
            matrix.Matrix[1][0] = 8;
             matrix.Matrix[1][1] = 0;
             matrix.Matrix[1][2] = 7;
             matrix.Matrix[2][0] = 8;
             matrix.Matrix[2][1] = 9;
             matrix.Matrix[2][2] = -4;
            WrappedVector vector = linearizedMatrix(matrix);

            cout << vector << endl;

            WrappedMatrix matrix1;
        matrix1.n = 3;
        matrix1.Matrix = new int * [matrix1.n];
        matrix1.Matrix[0] = new int[matrix1.n];
        matrix1.Matrix[1] = new int[matrix1.n];
        matrix1.Matrix[2] = new int[matrix1.n];
        matrix1.Matrix[0][0] = 8;
        matrix1.Matrix[0][1] = 7;
        matrix1.Matrix[0][2] = 7;
        matrix1.Matrix[1][0] = -6;
        matrix1.Matrix[1][1] = 0;
        matrix1.Matrix[1][2] = 6;
        matrix1.Matrix[2][0] = 2;
        matrix1.Matrix[2][1] = 2;
        matrix1.Matrix[2][2] = 9;
        WrappedVector vector1 = linearizedMatrix(matrix1);

        cout << vector1 << endl;

        vector *= vector1;

        cout << vector;


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So your `operator*=` does not change `vector1` and you're asking why `vector1 *= vector2` does not change `vector1`?

Comment: This is a sock puppet [posting duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661621/trying-to-reload-an-operator-in-c-but-it-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: @melpomene that's exactly what I've asked

Answer (score 0):

It should be a member function

```
WrappedVector &operator*=(const WrappedVector &vector)
```

[Check the operator overloading examples here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)